# Rendering content from one array to another in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, encryption

this is my codes:

```
$this->data['users'] = $this->Ion_auth->usersdata();
foreach($users as $list){
    $data = array(
        'id' =>$list->id,
        'email' => $list->email,
        'username' => $list->username,
        'active' => $list->active
    );
}

$this->data['userslist'] = $data;
$this->render('users/users_list','public_master');
```

i want to get data from  Ion_auth as a model and userdata as a method then store them to $data as an array just to encrypt some of them like id before controller sent them to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are overwritting `$data` at each loop. So the only thing left when you assigne `$this->data['userslist'] = $data;` is the `$data` declared in the last iteration.

You could try the following :

```
$this->data['userslist'] = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
    $this->data['userslist'][] = array('id' =>$user->id,
                                       'email' => $user->email,
                                       'username' => $user->username,
                                       'active' => $user->active
    );
}

$this->render('users/users_list','public_master');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `$data` variable each time round the loop.
And you are not addressing the location where you put the results from the Ion call correctly in your `foreach` loop.

```
$this->data['users'] = $this->Ion_auth->usersdata();

foreach($this->data['users'] as $list){
    $data[] = array(
        'id' =>$list->id,
        'email' => $list->email,
        'username' => $list->username,
        'active' => $list->active
    );
}

$this->data['userslist'] = $data;
$this->render('users/users_list','public_master');
```